# AIR App - Load Externally hosted SWF, SWF load XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, air

Trying to wrap my head around this...

AIR application runs on local machine. (works)

AIR application loads in externally hosted SWFs. (works)

Are these SWFs being ran locally since the AIR application is running? Or Externally?

For instance am I able to attempt to load this from child SWF:

```
private var urlStr:String = "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\info.xml";
```

Also,

A couple of the SWFs that play, load in XML.  Local or from another server, neither of them loads.  The XML loader doesn't even trigger an success/error on either of them.

These SWFs both work, load xml and play perfect when I test them when publishing.

Any ideas?

CODE:

```
myXMLURL = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
myXLoader = new URLLoader();
myXLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
myXLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleError);
myXLoader.load(myXMLURL);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean with "ran locally ... Or externally"?
For your 2nd question: check sandbox restrictions and setup

Comment: The AIR application is launched locally (e.g. on the pc).  However, it pulls/loads in external SWFs from a server.  That part works, so are the SWFs playing locally or technically externally?  I ask this because I am trying to load in an xml file from the Desktop of the machine where the AIR application is running.  I have tried toggling the "publish settings" of the SWFs for Local Playback Security but to no avail.

Comment: In that case they are considered externally - there are options to configure your sandbox settings to allow those clips to load local XML - you have to be owner of the external files or at least know sandbox details regarding those swiffs.
For the exact sandbox configuration please refer to the documentation

Comment: Thanks dogsgod! Yes I am the owner/creator.  Last question, would I be setting sandbox settings on those independent SWFs or the AIR application?  I added a try catch on the load() and it is definitely catching an error.

Comment: Sorry, but I stopped active Flex development around 2 years ago - and I don't remember ...

Comment: the loaded swf behaves depending on what loadercontext and applicationdomain you set.

Comment: yeah its odd.  ive added an mms.cfg file in the proper places, as well as, changed my adobe security settings to allow access to a "tmp" folder on desktop.  The loaded SWF from an external domain loads fine however it still shows an error 2148 when trying to access an XML file within the "tmp" folder on desktop.  The SWF when published is also set to "access local files".